# No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\Customers". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a class in Lumen, as I am trying to implement the doctrine, here

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;

#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'customers')]
class Customers
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[GeneratedValue]
    private int|null $id=null;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $first;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $last;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $email;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $phone;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $gender;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $username;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $password;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $city;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING)]
    private string $country;
```

and when I did this

```
$config = ORMSetup::createAttributeMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$connection = DriverManager::getConnection($dbParams, $config);
$entityManager = new EntityManager($connection, $config);
$entityManager->persist($customerObj);
$entityManager->flush();
```

I got this error:

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\Customers". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

Why I'm getting this error?

This is the documentation that I am reading.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/basic-mapping.html#basic-mapping

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the namespace prefix `ORM` from the annotation, like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;

#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'customers')]
class Customers
{
    #[Id]
    #[Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[GeneratedValue]
    private int|null $id=null;

...
```

I only saw examples either without the namespace, or with `@ORM`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;

#[@ORM\Entity]
#[@ORM\Table(name: 'customers')]
class Customers
{
    #[@ORM\Id]
    #[@ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[@ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private int|null $id=null;
```

Comment: Just for info, Symfony defines the ORM namespace which explains why there are so many examples with ORM in them.  When using Doctrine standalone, no ORM is used out of the box.  Quite annoying actually.  But I do think you are right about needing to drop the ORM from the id attribute.